# Is there any way to get images from an instagram account since the new changes of the API (April 4th, 2018)?

Tags: instagram-api

Instagram API removed the following endpoint:

```
GET /users/search
```

which I was using to get images from my profile on my website.

Is there any way to do this now? I can't find any info since this is very new.

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering this as well. I cannot seem to find it. It seems to me that you need to use their Graph API, but that requires an extensive app. I think embedding Instagram is over now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get at least the newest 12 pictures from a public account by using this URL scheme:

```
https://www.instagram.com/[name_of_account]/?__a=1
```

You can parse the Json output and find the image-URL in `display_url`

This also works with hashtags and locations:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hawaii/?__a=1
```

Comment: Thank you aljosha, I would have few questions. Can we trust those links? I mean, is there any information about those links from Instagram or Facebook side? Can we use them for business or personal use? Are they going to change one day?

Comment: This URL often has problems, which is why there is another one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467565/error-when-scraping-instagram-media-by-adding-at-the-end-of-url-a-1

Answer (score 1):

you can show your own media, 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
just enter  access token an you will be able to get your media data

Comment: This works for me, which is weird but I don't mind. Probably gets shut off in the future. But for now, this is the solution for me.

Comment: it will not shut off because you are using your own profile

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any way via either the old Instagram API or via the new Facebook graph API for Instagram Business Accounts to get profile images for accounts that are not yours. If it is an Instagram Business Account, you could get the Facebook profile image from the Facebook page associated with that Instagram account; but if it is a non-business Instagram account, that won't work. More documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview

Comment: So it is basically impossible to retrieve images now? How does elfsight it then? https://elfsight.com/blog/2018/02/instagram-graph-api-changes/ down below you can type in any username. is that a dedicated app?

Comment: @HuubS not sure. could be page scraping perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure as well, but with the answer below I could get my simple page plugin back to work